# How to label and group unique features in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, label

new to python here. I have the following example array:

```
a = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,0,0]
```

I want to label and slice the array according to unique values that occur in succession, i.e. identical elements that occur in succession are to be assigned the same labels and with different labels otherwise. This is to be to be done without the need to be separated by `zeros` for assigning different labels, as one would do with something like  [scipy.ndimage.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label).

Thus, the output with `scipy.ndimage.label` is not what I expect :

```
lbl = label(a)
lbl = [0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0]
```

As you can see, it combined the whole sequence of `[...,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...]` as one label instead of four unique labels. Whereas what i want is something like this:

```
lbl = [0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,0,0]
```

Have i missed something with the function or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Edited to make it clear based on my understanding. Feel free to edit further if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one approach -

```
def label_based_on_shifts(a):
    # Detect starts of each label(element is non-zero and is different 
    # from the previous element)
    mask = np.r_[a[0]!=0,(a[1:] != a[:-1]) & (a[1:] !=0)]

    # Setup id array, which when cumulatively summed would lead us to
    # labelled islands
    out = mask.astype(np.uint64).cumsum()    

    # Set the islands that are zeros in input array to be zeros in o/p too
    out[a==0] = 0
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [53]: a
Out[53]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0])

In [54]: label_based_on_shifts(a)
Out[54]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0])
```

**Approach #2 :** Another one to replace `np.cumsum` with `np.repeat` -

```
def label_based_on_shifts_v2(a):
    mask = np.r_[True,(a[1:] != a[:-1]),True]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)

    valid_idx_mask = a[idx[:-1]]!=0
    starts = idx[:-1][valid_idx_mask]
    stops = idx[1:][valid_idx_mask]
    lens = stops-starts

    out = np.zeros(len(a), dtype=int)
    out[a!=0] = np.repeat(np.arange(1,len(starts)+1), lens)
    return out
```